# Set a default printer with C#

Tags: c#

I have a C# program that accesses a database in order to print detailed reports in Excel.

Is there any way I can use the program to change the default printer so I can print different reports onto different printers. (one is A3 size the other is A4).

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to change default printer in OS or just print to different printers from your application?

Comment: Assign the [Document.ActivePrinter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.activeprinter%28v=office.14%29.aspx) property.

Comment: I just want one report to print to one printer and an other report to go to a different printer

Comment: I have managed to set the printer with ws.PrintOutEx(ActivePrinter: FilePaths.Default.CaravanPrinter);